# MIPS simple function

Tags: mips

I'm trying to study for computer architecture but I am stumped at how to do this problem. It's on the study guide and I want to know how to do it before the midterm. I get how to call a subroutine and how to do the stack. Just not the binary bit part.

**Write a function that returns how many binary bits are in a decimal number that is passed by the caller program? (use stack to keep track of registers)**

Thanks.

Comment: All you need is a loop with `AND`, `SLL`, and a counter. Read up on bitwise logic if you don't know how that works, and consult the instruction set reference for details on those instructions.

Comment: Thank, you. I was able to talk to my professor and that's pretty much what he said. He suggested to shift right one bit at a time and compare it to $zero. If it's not equal, increment, and shift again.